# Android. Как сгенерировать видео программно?

Tags: java, android, видео, content

Мне необходимо генерировать видео передвижений элементов по экрану. Нагуглил два варианта:
   1. Создавать скриншоты и сделать их них видео
   2. Запись экрана с помощью MediaProjection
оба не совсем подходят потому что необходимо отобразить на экране то что нужно записать в видео, мне бы хотелось этого избежать.

Может кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Подскажите как делали это и я буду рад любым идеям

Comment: Так если вам все равно необходимо записывать передвижения элементов по экрану почему бы не пользоваться либами записи экрана?

Comment: Я подумал что может есть способы, сделать это не отображая пользователю..

Comment: Есть. Если речь идёт о изображениях без отображения то, например, можно использовать библиотеку ffmpeg для java. При помощи неё можно сделать видео из последовательности изображений

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать